# Make a change to pose through all frames

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, keyframes, pose-mode

I started animating before even considering the hand pose of my model, and now, when my character runs, he looks like a karate chopping maniac.  I would hate to have to start reanimating from the ground up, so is there a way to change the hand pose and apply it all existing frames?

Comment: can you upload the .blend? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/